# Cosmos DB MongoDB API can't call Stored Procedures / UDF /

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

Pseudo Code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const con = mongoose.connect(config.uri, config.options, (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    const User = con.model('User');
    User.db.db.command({ testProcedure: 1 }, console.log);
})
```

Error Output:

```
{ MongoError: Command is not supported
    at /home/username/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:580:63
    at authenticateStragglers (/home/username/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:503:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/home/username/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:539:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/home/username/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:309:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/username/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:452:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:607:20)
  _t: 'OKMongoResponse',
  ok: 0,
  code: 115,
  errmsg: 'Command is not supported',
  '$err': 'Command is not supported',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} } null
```

Goal is to do following inside MongoDB (link goes to their own node.js SDK):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/storedprocedure?view=azure-node-latest#execute

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SapuSeven I want to execute a Stored Procedure inside Cosmos DB... As the title of the question states. (UDF = User Defined Function) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction

Answer (score 2):

Stored Procedures and UDFs are aspects of the native SQL (DocumentDB) API and associated SDKs. MongoDB SDKs (or frameworks tailored to work with MongoDB, such as Mongoose that you're using) know nothing about Cosmos DB's stored procs or UDFs.

You would need to use the Cosmos DB SDKs for your specific language to take advantage of these. However, I doubt they will work properly against a database set up using the MongoDB API.

Comment: Pretty answer .